# Html popup div fullscreen inside another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a fullscreen popup over the whole page, but I've only found that you need to place it at the body root

```
<body>
   <div id="popup" >
      ...
   </div>
   <div id="page">
      <div id="content" >...</div>
   </div>
</body>
```

But that's not what I need. I need to have a fullscreen popup adding it inside the page.

```
<body>
   <div id="page">
      <div id="popup" >
         ...
      </div>
      <div id="content" >
         ...
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

The problem is that if I do this, the popup is not fullscreen, but it appears only over the "page" div, while I want it to be fullscreen

I added a live example https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GS0R8SGBW8CS as you can see the popup is not entirely full screen

Comment: Please update your question so it includes a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without your CSS and/or JS we cannot figure out what is (or isn't) wrong. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources for more info.

Comment: Try using `position:static`

Comment: @reyno Hi, I added a live example

Comment: @JeremyThille I've done that, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Might the problem be caused by the style="margin: 2rem;" on the #popup? I don't see why to place a margin on a popup that you would want to have fullscreen.

Comment: Unfortunately it works on the live that I made but not on my complex website :/ I don't understand why

Comment: Solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68301717/16406161

Comment: Just [accept your own answer](/help/accepted-answer) if you have found a solution to your problem. Take the [tour] to learn how [so] works.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that I had a parent div with the clip style attribute. I removed it and now the popup is fullscreen. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Remove style="margin:2rem" from popup div

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GS0RIDZF6HMF

Comment: Unfortunately it works on the live that I made but not on my complex website :/ I don't understand why

Comment: Solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68301717/16406161

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
.Docdiv
{
position:relative;
z-index: 2;
width:1000px; overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
top: 3%;bottom: 3%;
right:183px; 
color: black;
}
</style>

<div  class="Docdiv" style="min-height: 100%;">
                        
</div>
```

Comment: Solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68301717/16406161